# Update 20,000 rows with same value using MySQL

Tags: mysql, command-line

In a MySQL table with over 500,000 rows, how can I update 20,000 rows with the same value for the same column?

I have a processed column that is by default `0`, I want to update it to `3` so that those 20,000 entries are not picked for processing.

What I have tried so far: I created a file with a list of all 20,000 ID's and tried this query:

`update table set processed=3 where id in (...)`

I then tried pasting the list of id's in the `...` but it made the system hang.

#### Edit:

In the table, there are other rows that I wish to remain `processed=0` and so a `set processed=3 where processed=0` won't work. I have to target specific row by ID.

Comment: So you want to replace every instance of `0` to `3`?

Comment: update table set processed=3 where processed = 0;

Comment: I am not sure your clarification is very clear. Would you expand on that? What does `target specific row by ID` mean?

Comment: @halfer: It means the rows to update cannot be identified from their current values, only from their individual unique IDs (let's pretend those aren't values) ... meaning the only option is something that can list 20,000 IDs in the `UPDATE` statement (or equivalent).

Comment: Ah thanks @Lightness, I assumed it was a sub-select in there, in fact it's just a comma-separated set of IDs. That makes sense!

Comment: @halfer: At a glance, `WHERE id IN (...)` is easy to misread as `WHERE id IN SELECT(...)`, I'll give you that :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

I created a PHP script that fetches the id from the file with id's then using a for loop creates a query and updates that row specifically:

ID Files:

```
5351245
5351246
5351247
...
5373362
5373363
5373364
```

PHP Script:

```
$file = "ids.txt";
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "[USERNAME]", "[PASSWORD]", "[DATABASE]");

$handle = fopen($file, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($id = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $sql = "UPDATE responses SET bucketID=0, processed=3 WHERE messageID=".$id.";";
        if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
            echo "Record $id was updated successfully.\n";
        } else {
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link)."\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: You're running 20,000 `UPDATE`s. The PHP script is a reasonable idea, but I would at least have built and dispatched the `UPDATE` statements in chunks of, say, 1000 rows.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And how would you do that?

Comment: Have a crack at it and let me see the result - I'll give some feedback.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nice. Give me a moment.